# InnoDB converting to MyISAM on Import

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam, my.cnf

I'm running a MySQL 5.1 server under CentOS 6.5. During an import of a SQL file today, all tables were created under MyISAM, even if they were declared to use InnoDB engine.

For example, I had a table declared on the .sql file as this:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
[....]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

When the .sql file was imported using:

```
mysql -u <username> -p < new_db.sql
```

The customer table was created using the MyISAM table. How can this be possible?

To fix the issue I have added on MySQL config to set the default engine to InnoDB and restarted but, since the table engine was declared to be InnoDB, shouldn't it be loaded using that declared engine instead of the default ?

Comment: Are you sure, that the table doesnt exists already?

Comment: Yeah. The script is generated by MySQL Dump so whenever a table exists it drops and then re-create's it.

Comment: Maybe InnoDB failed to initialize and MySQL converted InnoDB table into MyISAM?

Comment: It's possible that the installation of MySQL doesn't support InnoDB at all. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb'`. If InnoDB isn't available, this would explain the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.1 have some problems. I prefere to update it.

The other way is to disable different InnoDB settings in your my.cnf until innoDB is running.

```
 show engine innodb status
```

With this command you can check the current state. Dont forget to restart mysql after every change.

Comment: The problem with that is that it is a server with 200 databases and at least 50 tables each so it would be a killer doing that ...

Comment: Do you have large tables?

Comment: A whole lot of them. One of the tables holds daily transactions so it can get brutally big.

Comment: can you try to execute only one of your CREATE queries? Without INSERTs. Check after that the enginge

Comment: from the command line I did that and it loaded as MyISAM. That is why this is so weird. I haven't seem MySQL behaving like that.

Comment: I ran that and also ran ```show engines```. Here is a curve ball. Server1 where all is correct and dumps are generated from has MyISAM as default engine and Server2 that I'm trying to restore has InnoDB as default enigne (after setting on my.cnf and restart) and only after the restart it started to load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time searching for an explanation of the issue I have found none, but there are ways to prevent the issue and to fix it.

1st - Check this MySQL configuration: `no engine substitution`. It will help to avoid the issue. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution

2nd - When the error is happening, use both `show_warnings` and `show_engines` to see any errors that occurred and to see if InnoDb is enabled. You can also use `show engine innodb status` to gather detailed information.

3rd - Since MySQL 5.1 have by default MyISAM as the default engine, set mysql configuration to use InnoDB as the default engine.

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
default-table-type=InnoDB
```

And if all of that fails and you can't still find out why or what is happening, then, this might help:

```
$ sudo service mysqld stop
$ mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0.bak
$ mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1.bak
$ sudo service mysqld start
```

It doesn't properly explain why the issue happened but it will help solve it. My next step is verify if the server and application will support a MySQL update to 5.5